# Rails Association Issues in Controller Testing using Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I'm having issues trying to access my associated model in a one-to-many relationship during testing. I don't understand why the below doesn't return the association.

The reason I care about this problem is because I wanted to use Factory Girl to call my guardian through my_factory_girl_user.guardians.first which wasn't working. I tried to simplify by using just ActiveRecord and it still isn't behaving how I would expect.

I'm a true Rails beginner so any advice on this problem or how to better debug it would be much appreciated!

**Question: Why doesn't @target_user.guardians return anything?**

User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :guardians, dependent: :destroy
  ...
end
```

Guardian Model

```
class Guardian < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  ...
end
```

Controller Spec

```
describe 'PUT #update' do
context 'when logged in and authorized' do
  let(:new_attributes){
    {level: 31}
  }
  it 'sets current guardian' do
    @target_user = User.create!(profile_name: 'MyGuardian', system: 'Xbox One', region: 'North America', password: "password", password_confirmation: "password")
    @target_guardian = Guardian.create!(level: 31, guardian_class: 'Titan', activity: 'Vault of Glass', user_id: @target_user.id)
    puts "User: #{@target_user.inspect}"
    puts "Guardian: #{@target_guardian.inspect}"
    puts "user.guardians: #{@target_user.guardians}"
    put :update, {id: @target_guardian.id, guardian: new_attributes}, {user_id: @target_user.id}
    expect(assigns(:guardian)).to eq(@target_guardian)
  end
end
```

Output

```
User: #<User id: 3147, email: nil, password_digest: "$2a$04$QPk3kCsKLp0IX.YmMPAPdO2gCe79mwVybHkFpcEsVkG...", created_at: "2014-12-16 02:55:57", updated_at: "2014-12-16 02:55:57", is_admin: nil, profile_name: "MyGuardian", system: "Xbox One", region: "North America">
Guaridan: #<Guardian id: 3284, created_at: "2014-12-16 02:55:57", updated_at: "2014-12-16 02:55:57", user_id: 3147, fireteam_id: nil, level: 31, guardian_class: "Titan", activity: "Vault of Glass", comment: nil>
user.guardians:
```

**Answer:**

Thanks Typpex for the help! My issue was that I was not refreshing the User after creating the Guardian, the solution I used was adding the below line after creating my Guardian. For more information read the answer below.

```
@target_user.reload
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is because you never actually added the guardian to the user's guardian list such as:

```
@target_user.guardians << @target_guardian
```

Only after that you will be able to see guardians in @target_user.guardians.

When testing with rspec you need to call the action in your controller that is actualling adding the guardian to the guardians collection in user and then test if the guardian was correctly added with something like

```
@target_user.guardians.size.should_be 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I tried adding your suggestion and got the same output. I thought the way associations worked was based off the key; since I assigned the user_id to the guardian I thought it would link. I don't quite understand what I'm missing still.

Comment: Can you check if you target_user and target_guardian were correctly created? You can check that by doing
target_user.valid?.should_be true
target_guardian.valid.should_be true

If one of them is wrong you can see why by checking model.errors.inspect.

Actually you are right, when you do target_user.guardians << target_guardian it will fill the user_id field in guardian table :)

Comment: You were right, I forgot I had made a small change elsewhere that was throwing the output off. Your original suggestion did fix the association. I also tried target_user.reload which also worked. My understanding is that the underlying issue was that I needed to refresh target_user with the new values from the database after creating the guardian. Thanks for all your help!